# Cannot get content of div to store locally and load locally

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JS function to save and load content of a notepad I've made, locally.
I tried to replicate this for a div which contains times of a stopwatch.(see code below)

The stopwatch when paused will write it's time to this div to be saved, I want these times to save when I refresh / close and reopen the page.

It works for my notes in the notepad, please can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

JavaScript for save function:

```
  //Storage of Text-Box
  
  const notesInput = document.querySelector('#notes');
  function remFunc() {
    // store the entered name in web storage
    localStorage.setItem('notes', notes.value);
  }
  
  function loadfunc() {
    
    if(localStorage.getItem('notes')) {
      let notes_var = localStorage.getItem('notes');
      notes.value= notes_var;
    } else {
    }
  }
  
  document.body.onload = loadfunc();


 //Storage of Times DIV
    
    const output = document.querySelector('#output');
    function remfunc2() {  
      localStorage.setItem('output', outContent.innerHTML);
    }
    
    function loadfunc2() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('output')) {
        let output_var = localStorage.getItem('output');
        output.innerHTML = output_var ;
      } else {
        
      }
    }
    
    document.body.onload = loadfunc2();
```

This is the div:

```
<div id="output" name="output" class="buttonZ logPad"></div>
```

Here is the stopwatch Javascript:

```
  // Timer JS
  
  var flagclock = 0;
  var flagstop = 0;
  var stoptime = 0;
  var splitcounter = 0;
  var currenttime;
  var splitdate = '';
  var output;
  var clock;
  
  function startstop()
  {
    var startstop = document.getElementById('startstopbutton');
    var startdate = new Date();
    var starttime = startdate.getTime();
    if(flagclock==0)
    {
      startstop.value = 'Stop';
      flagclock = 1;
      counter(starttime);
    }
    else
    {
      startstop.value = 'Start';
      flagclock = 0;
      flagstop = 1;
      splitdate = '';
      logTime();
    }
  }
  
  function counter(starttime)
  {
    output = document.getElementById('output');
    clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    currenttime = new Date();
    var timediff = currenttime.getTime() - starttime;
    if(flagstop == 1)
    {
      timediff = timediff + stoptime
    }
    if(flagclock == 1)
    {
      clock.innerHTML = formattime(timediff,'');
      clock.setAttribute('value', formattime(timediff, ''));
      refresh = setTimeout('counter(' + starttime + ');',10);
    }
    else
    {
      window.clearTimeout(refresh);
      stoptime = timediff;
    }
  }
  
  function formattime(rawtime,roundtype)
  {
    if(roundtype == 'round')
    {
      var ds = Math.round(rawtime/100) + '';
    }
    else
    {
      var ds = Math.floor(rawtime/100) + '';
    }
    var sec = Math.floor(rawtime/1000);
    var min = Math.floor(rawtime/60000);
    ds = ds.charAt(ds.length - 1);
    if(min >= 60)
    {
      startstop();
    }
    sec = sec - 60 * min + '';
    if(sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) != '')
    {
      sec = sec.charAt(sec.length - 2) + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
      sec = 0 + sec.charAt(sec.length - 1);
    }
    min = min + '';
    if(min.charAt(min.length - 2) != '')
    {
      min = min.charAt(min.length - 2)+min.charAt(min.length - 1);
    }
    else
    {
      min = 0 + min.charAt(min.length - 1);
    }
    return min + ':' + sec + ':' + ds;
  }
  
  function resetclock()
  {
    flagstop = 0;
    stoptime = 0;
    splitdate = '';
    window.clearTimeout(refresh);
    
    if(flagclock !== 0) {
      startstopbutton.value = 'Start';
      flagclock = 0;
      flagstop = 1;
      splitdate = '';
    }
    
    
    if(flagclock == 1)
    {
      var resetdate = new Date();
      var resettime = resetdate.getTime();
      counter(resettime);
    }
    else
    {
      clock.innerHTML = "00:00:0";
    }
  }
  
  //Split function
  
  function splittime()
  {
    if(flagclock == 1)
    {
      if(splitdate != '')
      {
        var splitold = splitdate.split(':');
        var splitnow = clock.innerHTML.split(':');
        var numbers = new Array();
        var i = 0
        for(i;i<splitold.length;i++)
        {
          numbers[i] = new Array();
          numbers[i][0] = splitold[i]*1;
          numbers[i][1] = splitnow[i]*1;
        }
        if(numbers[1][1] < numbers[1][0])
        {
          numbers[1][1] += 60;
          numbers[0][1] -= 1;
        }
        if(numbers[2][1] < numbers[2][0])
        {
          numbers[2][1] += 10;
          numbers[1][1] -= 1;
        }
      }
      splitdate = clock.innerHTML;
      output.innerHTML += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + clock.innerHTML + '\n';
    }
  }
  function logTime() {
    const time = document.getElementById('clock').getAttribute('value');
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML += (++splitcounter) + '. ' + time + '<br />'; 
  }
  
  function time() {
    splittime();
    resetclock();            
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you convert this code to Code snippet or jsfiddle?

Comment: Your stopwatch logic doesn't make a call to localStorage.setItem(..) anywhere so there wouldn't ever be any localStorage data to retrieve.  Hint: you probably want to save the data to lcoal storage inside the logTime() function logic.

Comment: You assign `notes_var` to  `output.value`, not `output_var`

Comment: Also you can't assign to the `value` of a `div`, you need to assign to the `innerHTML` or `textContent`. And the `div` variable is called `outContent` not `output`

Comment: @Drew the localStorage command in console shows the data is stored correctly, I just cant seem to get it to load

Comment: @MattEllen Even after fixing this, still the same issue

Comment: @MattEllen I have tried innerHTML, both this and value provide an error in the console, and ive fixed the variable names

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out what I was doing wrong.
The 'output' variable was being used in the timer code.
This prevented me from setting the variable correctly.
I changed the id for the div and the variable name i was using.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code in my console on this page and it is working:

```
let counter = 0;

const outContent = document.querySelector('#notify-container');

setInterval(function()
{
  counter++;
  outContent.innerHTML = `${counter*2} seconds`;
  localStorage.setItem('output', outContent.innerHTML);
}, 2000);

function loadfunc2() {
  if(localStorage.getItem('output')) {
    let output_var = localStorage.getItem('output');
    outContent.innerHTML = output_var ;
    counter = parseInt(outContent.innerHTML.split(' ')[0], 10)
  }
}
loadfunc2()
```

Paste it into the console, run it, leave it for a few seconds, then refresh the page, paste it and run it again. You can see it working.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, its still the same as before, I check localStorage in the console and it stores the values, I just cant get it to load them again.

Comment: @SeanCompton I've updated my anwer. what is different between what I'm doing and what you're doing?